# Compact iff every family of nonempty subsets has an accumulation point

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In [this](https://algebra.enigma-software.net/fileadmin/pdfs/Abstracts-AGMT2/Fornasiero.pdf) presentation (slide $14$) the author states that a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is compact if and only if every family of nonempty subsets of $X$ has an accumulation point.

> What does he means by accumulation point of a family of sets?

It might be that we can assume in his statement that the union of the family is infinite.

I've considered the property (A): every infinite subset has an accumulation point. I've noted that every compact space satisfies (A) but the space $[0,\omega_1)$ with the order topology, where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal, seems to be a counterexample to the converse. So compactness is stronger than (A).

If I interpret "accumulation point of a family of sets" to mean accumulation point of the union of said family then the author's statement cound simply mean  (A) $\Leftrightarrow$ compact, which is not true.

If I interpret it to mean accumulation point of at least one set in the family then the statement makes no sense since in a $T_1$ space every infinite family of singletons would have no accumulation points.

I'm stuck here.

Comment: Usually only filter bases are said to have accumulation points, which is a point in the intersection of their closures. This is equivalent to compactness (use the FIP formulation e.g.) It's mentioned in an early slide. But for any family it makes no sense to demand accumulation points.

Comment: Or maybe they mean a [complete accumulation point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#complete_accumulation_point).

Comment: @orole do you know if "every infinite set has a complete accumulation point " is equivalent to compactness?

Comment: That is [a characterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Equivalent_definitions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a family of nonempty subsets of $X$ and $x\in X$.

We say that $x$ is **an accumulation point** of $\mathcal{C}$ if,
for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, there exists $C\in \mathcal{C}$ such that, for every $B\in\mathcal{C}$, if $B\subseteq C$, then $U\cap B \neq \emptyset$.

This is equivalent to compactness.